# How can I do an efficient in-place sort on an arbitrary indexable collection?

Tags: python, sorting, in-place

### Question

**How can I use Python's inbuilt sort (or similar) to do an *in-place* sort on a arbitrary collection** (which supports `__len__`, `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` methods)?

### Background

The question arose from considering the following problem (somewhat related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63753064/how-to-sort-two-lists-based-on-one-first-and-the-other-next-in-python)). Suppose that I have two large lists of equal length:

```
hours   = [20, 21, 18, 18, 19]
minutes = [15, 14, 13, 12, 11]
```

(in this example representing the times 20:15, 21:14, etc).

I want to sort these lists together in-place as pairs of values from the two lists (such as those retured by `zip`), to give:

```
hours   = [18, 18, 19, 20, 21]
minutes = [12, 13, 11, 15, 14]
```

One could implement this by encapsulating both lists into a custom collection that uses paired values when indexing, and then sorting that collection.

Here's the collection class:

```
class Times:
    
    def __init__(self, hours, minutes):
        if len(hours) != len(minutes):
            raise ValueError('lists must be of same length')
        self.hours = hours
        self.minutes = minutes

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return (self.hours[i], self.minutes[i])

    def __setitem__(self, i, vals):
        self.hours[i], self.minutes[i] = vals

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.hours)
```

We can sort the underlying lists in a memory-efficient way by doing an in-place sort on the top-level collection.  But the following example uses a CPU-inefficient sorting algorithm.

```
def bubble_sort(x):
    n = len(x)
    for last in range(n-1, 0, -1): 
        for pos in range(last):
              if x[pos] > x[pos+1] : 
                  x[pos], x[pos+1] = x[pos+1], x[pos] 

hours   = [20, 21, 18, 18, 19]
minutes = [15, 14, 13, 12, 11]
times = Times(hours, minutes)

bubble_sort(times)

print(hours)     # [18, 18, 19, 20, 21]
print(minutes)   # [12, 13, 11, 15, 14]
```

Alternatively, we can use Python's more efficient builtin `sorted`, but then we are allocating more memory because it is not sorting in-place.

```
hours   = [20, 21, 18, 18, 19]
minutes = [15, 14, 13, 12, 11]
times = Times(hours, minutes)

for i, v in enumerate(sorted(times)):
    times[i] = v

print(hours)    # [18, 18, 19, 20, 21]
print(minutes)  # [12, 13, 11, 15, 14]
```

So it would be desirable to be able to do an *in-place* sort using Python's inbuilt sort (or something similar).  Here is a failed attempt to use `list.sort` on something other than a list -- it isn't supported:

```
>>> list.sort(times)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: descriptor 'sort' requires a 'list' object but received a 'instance'
```

How can this be done?

Comment: I think you have to manually sort these, can't be done using a library function

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "in-place"?

Comment: @superbrain I mean modifying the collection rather than producing a separate copy. Essentially here I am also interested in using an O(1) amount of additional memory.

Comment: O(1) additional memory rules out any `list.sort` solution, as that's not O(1) but O(n).

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realise that. (Also just noting here that I will be offline for a while so will respond to any further comments later.)

Comment: Can you [please vote to undelete and reopen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64274973/548225)