# How regex a number length 7 in a string but the number is not start with 0 in Python?

Tags: python, regex, string, numbers

I have a string like this:

```
s = "Abc 3456789 cbd 0045678 def 12345663333"
print(re.findall(r"(?<!\d)\d{7}(?!\d)", s))

Ouput is : 3456789  and 0045678
```

but I only want to get 3456789. How can I do that?

Comment: Both 45678  and 00456 are not 7 digit numbers

Comment: It seems from your "I only want to get 45678" that you maybe you want numbers that are *not* 7 digits long (despite the title). The question is a bit confusing because of this.

Comment: It looks like the example string has totally changed since I started answering. And the question is still wrong: the output of the command you use is *not* what you claim it to be. And when you say that you want to get 45678, this makes even less sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per title of finding 7 digit numbers that don't start with `0` you may use:

```
(?<!\d)[1-9]\d{6}(?!\d)
```

Note `[1-9]` at start of match before matching next 6 digits to make it total 7 digits.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/cMyHfK/1)

To make it match any number that doesn't start with `0` use:

```
(?<!\d)[1-9]\d*(?!\d)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it: `^\D+(\d+)\s`

At the beginning of the string `^`, there are any non digit characters `\D+`, followed by any number of digits `\d+`, which are captured `(\d+)`, and need to be followed by a whitespace `\s`.

See: https://regex101.com/r/ZuGJ7l/1

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for number not beginning with 0, then use `[1-9]` for the first digit and `\d` for the remaining digits.

For example, to find the ones of length 7 (as per the title), this would give you:

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\d)[1-9]\d{6}(?!\d)', s)
```

in other words, a non-zero digit followed by 6 digits, the whole thing neither preceded nor followed by a digit (per the negative lookahead and negative lookbehind assertions),

which for your current example string would produce:

```
['3456789']
```

If you want ones that are *not* length 7, you could use:

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\d)[1-9](?:\d{,5}|\d{7,})(?!\d)', s)
```

in other words, a non-zero digit followed by either <= 5 or >= 7 digits (i.e. any number other than 6), the whole thing neither preceded nor followed by a digit,

which would give:

```
['12345663333']
```

Note in the second case the use of `?:` to ensure that the bracketed group is a non-capturing one -- this ensures that `re.findall` will return everything that is matched, rather than the contents of the parentheses.

Comment: I noticed after posting this that Anu Bhava's solution already posted has the same regex for getting numbers that **do** have 7 digits. However, there is significant confusion about whether the question is looking for numbers that **do** or **don't** have 7 digits, because the example in the question (namely: "I only want to get 45678") contradicts the title. As this answer also addresses that case (*not* 7 digits), I am going to leave it here.

Comment: Answer now updated to reflect changed examples in the question.

Comment: yes. I'm sorry for this case I was uncareful. I have updated it and your answer is totally right too but I only can choose one answer. Thank you so much for your help.