# Is there a python function for sorting a 2D array based on both elements in the nested array?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, lambda

So I have a list that looks like this: `people_list = [[str name, int numerical value]]` where there are n amounts of lists inside of `people_list`. With actual data, it would look like this: `people_list = [['jim', 30000], ['james', 30000]]`. I need to sort this list first based on the numerical value in each nested list, so sorted based on `people_list[i][1]` where `i` is the nth nested list, and the entire `people_list needs` to be sorted from highest to lowest numerical value. Then if there are any ties in the numerical value I need to sort the tied lists alphabetically based on the name, so `people_list[i][0]`.

I tried the code below to sort, but the output was not exactly how I needed it, and I haven't found any other resources online to get it to sort how I need to.

```py
people_list = [['jim', 33000], ['james', 22000], ['john', 33000], ['zack', 10000]]
sorted_by_int_then_name = sorted(people_list, key=lambda person: (person[1], person[0]), reverse=True)
```

The output for this code is:

```py
>>> sorted_by_int_then_name
[['john', 33000], ['jim', 33000], ['james', 22000], ['zack', 10000]]
```

This is sorted correctly numerically, but the names are not sorted alphabetically like I need them to be. I think the issue I'm having might be because I'm using the `reverse=True` parameter, but if I don't include that parameter then the list is sorted from lowest numerical value to highest. The output I am looking for would be this:

```py
>>> sorted_by_int_then_name
[['jim', 33000], ['john', 33000], ['james', 22000], ['zack', 10000]]
```

How can I properly sort by numerical value for `people_list[i][1]` and then by `people_list[i][0]` whenever the numerical value is tied?

I am running this code using python version 3.8.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to multiply the integer by `-1` instead of using `reverse=True`:

```
people_array = [['jim', 33000], ['james', 22000], ['john', 33000], ['zack', 10000]]
sorted_by_int_then_name = sorted(people_array, key=lambda person: (-1 * person[1], person[0]))
print(sorted_by_int_then_name)
```

**Output**

```
[['jim', 33000], ['john', 33000], ['james', 22000], ['zack', 10000]]
```

As an alternative, and taking advantage of the fact that [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) is [stable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Stable_sorts), use a two-pass sort:

```
from operator import itemgetter

people_array = [['jim', 33000], ['james', 22000], ['john', 33000], ['zack', 10000]]
sorted_by_int_then_name = sorted(people_array, key=itemgetter(0))
sorted_by_int_then_name.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
print(sorted_by_int_then_name)
```

**Output**

```
[['jim', 33000], ['john', 33000], ['james', 22000], ['zack', 10000]]
```

The two-pass sort can be faster, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69468552/efficiency-of-sorting-by-multiple-keys-in-python).